# localtime returns null in visual studio 2015 when _USE_32BIT_TIME_T is set as part of preprocessor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, max, localtime

We have a legacy project where we need to get the max epoch time supported which was achieved by the following code snippet:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>      /* puts, printf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime */

#define LONG_MAX      2147483647L // maximum (signed) long value
int main()
{
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    long elapsedTime = LONG_MAX;
    time_t temp = elapsedTime;
    timeinfo = localtime(&temp);
    printf("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The good thing is it used to work until visual studio 2015 migration. 
After migration though the localtime() returns null. 
This happens only when we pass the pre processor argument **_USE_32BIT_TIME_T** .
Without which it returns the proper max value 03:14:07, January 19, 2038, UTC.

Is there any known issue due to the use of _USE_32BIT_TIME_T pre processor in 2015.

Comment: no worries .. figured it .. looks like msdn has implemented stricter checking for the long value passed in 2015. #define LONG_MAX      2147463847L  needs to be passed to get the max time supported in 32 bit side.